# TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3 (Rock, paper, scissors game)

Tags: python

Keep getting this syntax error

> TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
from random import randint 
from tkinter import *

po = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

player = False
cpu = po[randint(0, 2)]

while player == False:
    player = input("Rock", "Paper", "Scissors?")
    if player == computer:
        print("Tie")
    elif player == "Rock":
        if computer == "Paper":
            print("You lose!", computer, "covers", player)
        else:
            print("You win!", player, "smashes", computer)
    elif player == "Paper":
        if computer == "Scissors":
            print("You lose!", computer, "cuts", player)
        else:
            print("You win!", player, "covers", computer)
    elif player == "Scissors":
        if computer == "Rock":
            print("You lose!", computer, "smashes", player)
        else:
            print("You win!", player, "cut", computer)
    else:
        print("That's not a valid play. Check your spelling!")

    player = False
    computer = po[randint(0,2)]
```

Comment: I think you meant `input("Rock, Paper, Scissors?")` Notice how that's one string, instead of three separate strings as your example has it.

Comment: The error is clearly saying that `input` expects at most one argument, but you're passing three. Why are you passing three arguments to `input`?

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing `input`. The argument passed to it is merely the prompt presented, and thus can only be a single string.

```
player = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors?")
```

Is probably more like what you want.

Comment: Then the player wouldn't be able to pick one in particular?

Comment: There's no way force them to type only one of those strings. You'll have to check to make sure what they typed is valid.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you never really give the person a chance to input wether rock, paper, or scissors, you should probably do something along the lines of

```
player = str(input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?"))
```

That way player is assigned to whichever the player chooses